# Polly Retry always throws System.AggregateException instead of custom exception

Tags: c#, .net, polly, retrypolicy

As the title says, I created a retry mechanism using Polly. The problem is that I always get a System.AggregateException instead of my own custom exception. I will add the code here.

This is the polly static class which I created:

```
public static class PollyExtension
{
    public static Task<T> RetryRequestWithPolicyAsync<T,T1>(
        Func<Task<T>> customAction,
        int retryCount,
        TimeSpan pauseSecondsBetweenFailures) where T1 : Exception
    {
        return 
            Policy
            .Handle<T1>()
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(retryCount, i => pauseSecondsBetweenFailures).ExecuteAsync(() => customAction?.Invoke());
    }
}
```

Here is that actuall call of the retry polly:

```
   var result= await PollyExtension.RetryRequestWithPolicyAsync<int, CustomException>( () =>
        {
            if (1 + 1 == 2)
            {
                throw new MyException("test");
            }
            else
            {
                throw new CustomException("test");
            }
        },
       1,
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

My expectations are that if I throw MyException then, polly will also throw MyException to the caller method. Instead the exception thrown is System.AggregateException.

What I am doing wrong here ? Thanks

EDIT 1: after more debug it seems that AggregateException has as inner exception MyException. Is this intended behaviour or I am doing something wrong ?

Comment: I'm unable to repro this with the code you posted. I don't see an `AggregateException` at all when I run this code.

Comment: Check the remarks section about the use of the AggregateException in this article:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=netcore-3.1

Below you will find a way to handle your own exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ExecuteAsync` call you are **not awaiting** the delegate.
The await keyword would unwrap your custom exception from the `AggregateException`.

Preferred way:

```
.ExecuteAsync(async () => await customAction?.Invoke());
```

Comment: This actually helped. I really missed that one. Thanks @Peter Csala

Comment: Hi @cozmin-calin I'm glad this "trick" helped you. Could you please mark this post as the answer? Thanks in advance.